# How can get the query sql instruction from this code zf2?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

how can get an sql query for this code in zf2 
is only that don't return my all records that i need only some ones columns
don.t get (nombre_pais, genero, ocupacion,sitio_web )

**i'm trying this code in mysql console (query)**
it returns ok

```
 SELECT album.id, album.artist, album.title, pais.nombre_pais, biografia.genero, biografia.ocupacion, biografia.sitio_web
                 FROM album
                    INNER JOIN pais ON  pais.id_album = album.id
                    INNER JOIN biografia ON biografia.id_album = album.id
        WHERE   1 = 1
AND album.artist like '%value_artist%'
AND album.artist LIKE '%value_title%'
```

**and this is my code in zf2 :**
it doesn't return ok. It returns only id, title, artist, and doesn't other columns from my other tables.

```
$where = new Where();
    if (isset($artist) and isset($title))
    {
    $where->like('album.title', '%' . $title . '%')
    ->like('album.artist', '%' . $artist . '%');
    }
    if (isset($artist))
    {
        $where->like('album.artist', '%' . $artist . '%');
    }
    if (isset($title))
    {
        $where->like('album.title', '%' . $title . '%');
    }
    $select = new Select();
    $select->from('album')
    ->columns(array ('id', 'artist','title'))
    ->join('pais', 'pais.id_album = album.id',array('nombre_pais'))
    ->join('biografia', 'biografia.id_album = album.id', array('genero', 'ocupacion', 'sitio_web'))
    ->where($where);
```

please some one help me to get my correct result

Comment: Joins looks fine, should work

Comment: Works for me. Doublecheck.

Comment: yeah of course don't return a error is only that don't show all columns show only (id, artist, title) but don't (genero, ocupacion, nombre_pais..etc)

Comment: Try and check that you're getting the query you expect. `echo $select->getSqlString();`

Comment: don't work i try this var_dump($select->getSqlString($this->adapter)); or only echo $select->getSqlString()); don;t work    thanks :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out what the generated SQL will look like, you can use the $select's getSqlString() method:

```
$select->getSqlString();
```

For example:

```
 echo $select->getSqlString(); die();
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html